# Dynamic data collection with Select2 and Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor, jquery-select2

I have set up a collection as the source for my data in a Select2 multiple select as so:

```
<template name="mySubjectsSelector">
    <div>
        <select id="mySubjects" data-placeholder="Choose your subjects" multiple>
            {{#each subjects}}
                <option>{{this.name}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
```

And the .js:

```
Template.mySubjectsSelector.subjects = function () {
    console.log("Fetching subjects...");
    return Subjects.find({}).fetch();
};

Template.mySubjectsSelector.rendered = function () {
    console.log("mySubjectsSelector is rendered!");
    $('#mySubjects')
        .select2({
            width: "300px"
        });
};
```

Whenever the Subjects collection is updated, it reactively re-renders the template, and that is fine, that's how I want it to behave. The unwanted behaviour, is that it will select the first option in the list when it is re-rendered, on ALL clients!

How can I avoid the selecting of the first item when it reloads/rerenders?

Comment: Oh, so what you want is that when your template re-renders because Subject changes, the Select2 controls maintain their current selection?

Comment: They could, but they could also just be reset to an original state. I just don't want them to select the top choice. I will post an image to show how it is behaving when I have the time.

Comment: did you find solution for this issue?

Comment: It's a long time ago, but I think I opted out of using Select2. I'll see if I can get the time to check the code sometime soon.

Answer (score 2):

What I did is create a blank first option.

```
<template name="mySubjectsSelector">
  <div>
    <select id="mySubjects" data-placeholder="Choose your subjects" multiple>
      <option></option>
      {{#each subjects}}
        <option>{{this.name}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

There's probably a smarter way of doing this, but it worked for me.

EDIT:

The more involved, Meteor-specific technique I have used to preserve values of the Select2 controls, by storing the values in a Session variable. Something like this:

```
Template.template.rendered = function () {

// assumes 1) all Select2 controls are originally <select> tags
//     and 2) all Select tags have ids assigned

  $('select').each(function (i) { 
    if (Session.get('preserve-' + this.id)) {
      $(this).val(Session.get('preserve-' + this.id));
    }
  });

  $('.select2').select2({ /* select2 code here */ })
  .on('change', function (e) {
    if (e.val !== "") {
      Session.set("preserve-" + e.target.id, e.val")
    }
  });

};
```

However: I may have not understood the question exactly. If you are only asking how using Select2 to allow unselected answers, try a `placeholder` and `allowclear`. From the docs:

```
$("#e2").select2({
  placeholder: "Select a State",
  allowClear: true
});
```

Comment: Yes, I did that too, but it does not fix my problem. That blank option will then be selected by all clients.

Comment: Added a couple other choices

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying a rule to preserve the `<select>` and `<option>` elements?

```
  Template.mySubjectsSelector.preserve({
      'select[id]': function (node) { return node.id; },
      'option': function (node) { return node.id; }
    });
```

Also see the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve).

Another problem could be that the `<option>` elements don't have ids. Also from the documentation:

> By default, new Meteor apps automatically include the preserve-inputs
>   package. This preserves all elements of type input, textarea, button,
>   select, and option that have unique id attributes or that have name
>   attributes that are unique within an enclosing element with an id
>   attribute. To turn off this default behavior, simply remove the
>   preserve-inputs package.

Comment: The problem is the Select2 plugin rewrites your select inputs into a bunch of divs, so after the plugin fires there's no select or option tags for preserve-inputs to actually preserve.